# Error "missing FROM-clause entry for table"

Tags: postgresql

When I use the following code, I get the error "missing FROM-clause entry for table zp". Does anyone know how I can eliminate this error?

```
SELECT SUM(zp.WP*et.GIS)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT zp.HHNR,zp.ZIELPNR FROM mobility.zielpersonen zp
FULL OUTER JOIN mobility.etappen et
ON zp.HHNR=et.HHNR AND zp.ZIELPNR=et.ZIELPNR
) as examp
```

Comment: *how I can eliminate this error?* don't use table names (`zp` & `et`) outside of their context (it is valid only in the sub-select; in the outer select, you only have `examp.HHNR` and `examp.ZIELPNR`).

Comment: but then it says that column "wp" does not exist. How can I use these variables then? Because actually I want to calculate the sum of  (wp * GIS) for people with distinct HHNR and ZIELPNR.

Comment: if you want distinct on HHNR and ZIELPNR, but you need the zp.WP and et.GIS columns, use `DISTINCT ON (zp.HHNR, zp.ZIELPNR) zp.WP, et.GIS`

Comment: This is a special [PostgreSQL extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) of DISTINCT, but if you need to create SQL compatible query, you have to use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

I would propose this as a guess:

```
SELECT SUM(exam.WP * exam.GIS)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT   zp.HHNR,
                        zp.ZIELPNR, 
                        zp.WP, 
                        et.GIS
    FROM mobility.zielpersonen zp
    FULL OUTER JOIN mobility.etappen et
    ON zp.HHNR=et.HHNR AND zp.ZIELPNR=et.ZIELPNR
) as examp
```

This is includes WP and GIS in the DISTINCT query and might or might not be what you want.

However, I think the most *natural* approach in this situation would be to just group by HHNR and ZIELPNR and calulate the SUM of the other values. This can be done by using this query:

```
SELECT zp.HHNR, zp.ZIELPNR, SUM(zp.WP*et.GIS) AS CalcResult
FROM mobility.zielpersonen zp
LEFT JOIN mobility.etappen et
ON zp.HHNR=et.HHNR 
AND zp.ZIELPNR=et.ZIELPNR
GROUP BY zp.HHNR, zp.ZIELPNR
```

I replaced the `OUTER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`, as I see no point in calculating/grouping the SUM for NULL values.

If neither of these options is what you want, please clarify the question!

Answer (score 0):

The `zp` and `et` table cannot be referred here:

```
SELECT SUM(zp.WP*et.GIS)
```

They can be referred only inside the subquery scope.

Simply try to do this:

```
SELECT SUM(examp.WP*examp.GIS)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT zp.HHNR,zp.ZIELPNR FROM mobility.zielpersonen zp
FULL OUTER JOIN mobility.etappen et
ON zp.HHNR=et.HHNR AND zp.ZIELPNR=et.ZIELPNR
) as examp
```

Comment: The columns WP and GIS do not exist  in the subquery output.

Comment: but then it says that column "wp" does not exist. How can I use these variables then? Because actually I want to calculate the sum of (wp * GIS) for people with distinct HHNR and ZIELPNR

Comment: what is "wp" and "GIS" then?

Comment: wp is a variable from zp, GIS is a variable from et. Both these tables share the variables HHNR and ZIELPNR. I would like to calculate (WP*GIS) for distinct HHNR and ZIELPNR